# Monitor color issues

Tags: display, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, colors, vga

I mean, you guys can check the pictures,

[image: good monitor]

[image: bad monitor]

On the good monitor, you know, it's all good, but on the second one, I can't see the highlight of a highlighted item, they are highlighted on both pictures for sure, can anyone help me figure out what I should change on monitor config? I tried some stuff, but it's pretty hard to know what I actually need to change.

Maybe I should point this out: the bad one is connected to the hdmi port on my graphics card through an adapter, the monitor is actually vga. its also a gtx 1070 if that helps.

Comment: has the 'bad' monitor always done this or did it start recently?

Comment: i just changed graphics card, from an hd 7970 to the gtx 1070 (it was ok before i guess), which is also giving me problems, because its hard as hell to get both monitors working with this new card

Comment: So, you have one HDMI display that's working fine, but the other VGA display (connected using an adapter) started behaving badly after the upgrade. Which 1070 do you have exactly? What brand/model?

Comment: Also, according to [this thread](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-3092457/vga-monitor-gtx-1070.html), NVIDIA practically killed support for analog displays. However, NVIDIA themselves [say](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4158/~/can-i-use-a-vga-monitor-with-the-geforce-gtx-1080%2F1070%2F1060-since-i-only-see-a) that it should work with a displayport to VGA adapter, perhaps you can try that.

Comment: thats what im looking into now, getting a displayport adapter.

Comment: how about this one: http://superuser.com/questions/1133834/win-10-black-screen-after-plugging-hdmi

Comment: What are the make and models of the monitors?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find online, it seems that nvidia isn't really trying to support analog signals (DVI-I, VGA) anymore, which is why you won't find any analog connectors on your GTX 1070.

[this](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4158/~/can-i-use-a-vga-monitor-with-the-geforce-gtx-1080%2F1070%2F1060-since-i-only-see-a) help article from nvidia says that using a DisplayPort to VGA connector should work. You could try that.

Answer (score 0):

What are the displays and what is the adapter?
More importantly - don't they have a DVI input?

Generally, VGA adapters can degrade the image quality; for example, I once bought a cheap DVI-VGA and immediately replaced it because the image was awful.

Perhaps a better solution for you (but still not preferable to a better adapter) would be a VGA-HDMI cable.